# Julia Multithreading a nested for loop for combinations of i & j

Tags: multithreading, julia

I have a question regarding multithreading in Julia and how to parallelize a for loop effectively.

Suppose you have a nested for loop and a computer with 4 cores. A straightforward way is to add `Threads.@threads` in front of the for loop. Assuming that the cores can run what they need to do without interference.

As I have understood this, only the outermost part of the nested for loop is parallelized. Assuming that N = 15 and M = 14 then a computer with 4 cores would be a bottleneck.

However, if you have a PC with 32 cores, then 32-15= 17 cores would be doing nothing. However, there would be 210 combinations in total to compute.

Is this correct? Is this how `Threads.@threads` work? Is there a way to parallelize the **combination** of both i and j. Perhaps using FLoops? I have tried to read the documentation, however, I need to know if I am going in a completely wrong direction.

```
Threads.@threads for i in 1:N
        for j in 1:M
                # Do stuff
        end
end
```

vs.

```
using FLoops

@floops for i in 1:N
        for j in 1:M
                # Do stuff
        end
end
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: In the latest Julia version you can apparently nest threads, so you can try putting `@threads` on both loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could probably have a third variable that you can divide into the two variables.

```
Threads.@threads for k in 1:(N*M)
                 j = k % M
                 i = k ÷ M
```

alternatively using [itertools.product](https://juliacollections.github.io/IterTools.jl/v0.2.1/) will assign both i and j without the two extra lines.

```
@floop for (i,j) in product(1:N,1:M)
```

Comment: How is this the answer to the question?

Comment: @Shayan because it parallelizes both i and j ....

Comment: This is mostly a shortcut and doesn't explain  *“Is this how Threads.@threads work? Is there a way to parallelize the combination of both i and j. Perhaps using FLoops?”*.

Comment: This was actually what I was looking for. I just needed a way to express both i and j as a combination. Then threading the loops was easy. The method using floop proved to be the most effective one. Threads.@threads seems to struggle with IterTools and product. Thank you!

Comment: To get Threads.@threads to work one would probably have to collect from the IterTools:

Threads.@threads for k in collect(IterTools.product(1:N,1:M))